# Google Place API for airports

Tags: google-places-api, google-nearby

I have a requirement to show airports close to a particular lat/long with a specific radius. For that, I used google search nearby APIs below.

My problem is that I want to get only airport info  but the problem is the API is fetching helipad too. How I can be more specific? Query URL :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=keyVal&location=lat,long&radius=10000&type=airport

Is there any way to filter the results to get airports only from the above ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's how this endpoint works. But there is always a way to filter results as per your requirement. I can help more if you provide the how the response JSON looks like.

Comment: Please find the API Info we have been using. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=keyVal&location=40.082470,-75.406612&radius=12000&type=airport